when unique_ptr implements pimpl, assignment in a class declaration also results in: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type '***'
excuse me, when I was implementing pimpl with std::unique_ptr, I accidentally found that when I set pimpl to nullptr in the header file, gcc(version 9.4.0,14.1.0) cannot be compiled. But cl.exe (version 19.20.27508.1) can be compiled, cancel the assignment, then can be compiled, I tried to find the possibility, but finally did not have an answer
The code is as follows:
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "feature.hpp"

int main() {
    auto wrap = std::make_shared<Wrap>();
    wrap->print666();
}

// feature.hpp
#include <memory>

class Wrap {
private:
    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl
        = nullptr  // This line assignment is key
        ;
public:
    Wrap();
    ~Wrap();
    void print666() const;
    void print888() const;
};

// feature.cpp
#include "feature.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class Wrap::Impl {
public:
    void print666() const {
        std::cout << "666" << std::endl;
    }

    void print888() const {
        std::cout << "888" << std::endl;
    }

};

void Wrap::print666() const {
    pimpl->print666();
}

void Wrap::print888() const {
    pimpl->print888();
}

Wrap::Wrap(): pimpl(new Impl){}
Wrap::~Wrap() = default;

The compile command is as follows:
# on linux
g++ -g -O0 -std=c++17 main.cpp feature.cpp -o main.out
# or on Windows
cl /EHsc /Femain.exe /std:c++17 main.cpp feature.cpp

(gcc9.4.0) When there is an assignment, the error message is as follows:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/memory:80,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::default_delete<_Tp>::operator()(_Tp*) const [with _Tp = Wrap::Impl]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:292:17:   required from ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = Wrap::Impl; _Dp = std::default_delete<Wrap::Impl>]’
feature.hpp:7:11:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:79:16: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘Wrap::Impl’
   79 |  static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~

I understand that the common reason for the above problems is that the deleter of std::unique_ptr needs to know the complete type of the Impl object, so it needs to implement the Wrap constructor and destructor after the Impl class definition appears. But I don't understand why assigning std::unique_ptr in the Wrap class declaration also causes this problem, because std::unique_ptr should not actually be initialized at this point, this initialization should be delayed to the Wrap constructor while the Impl is complete, so I think the msvc compiler is the expected behavior. Expect the correct explanation, thanks.

You will always initialize pimpl in the constructor, there's no need to do it inline in the class definition. And please note that it's not "assignment", but an actual initialization (which as I mentioned is not needed).

Besides that, the default constructor of a std::unique_ptr<T> (which isn't used in your shown code) will make it a null pointer, making the inline initialization even more redundant.

I believe that's because the line std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl = nullptr; is interpreted as std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl = std::unique_ptr<Impl>(nullptr); meaning that call a move constructor and a destructor to the unique pointer is performed. If you replace the line by std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl{nullptr}; then it will compile on all platforms.

Unrelated: you should default to -Og instead of -O0.

Or just drop the initialization and rely on default initialization in your constructor?

@ALX23z It's weird, since C++17, X x = X{}; should not require copy/move constructor (demo), and thus should not itself involve any destructor call.

@DanielLangr I've noticed the odd behaviour starting with std::atomic when inside classes std::atomic<int> x = 5; fails to compile as it requires copy contructor for std::atomic.

@ALX23z This fails to compile until C++17, since C++17 it doesn't fail: https://godbolt.org/z/xhE8fcT7P. Neither copy nor move constructor is needed anymore.

@Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your suggestion,I just think explicit is better than implicit, so I explicitly assigned nullptr to it, but the real initialization should be in the list initialization of the Wrap constructor (new Impl), so I think this piece should not affect it, but it won't compile. Initialization with std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl{nullptr} instead of std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl = nullptr will compile through (c++17), I don't understand

It's because std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl = nullptr; is the same as std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl = std::unique_ptr<Impl>(nullptr);. I.e. it creates a temporary object, and for that you need the full definition of Impl. With direct initialization (std::unique_ptr<Impl> pimpl{nullptr};) no such temporary object is created. And while I agree that sometimes being explicit is good, the behavior of the code is (or should be) so well-known that it's not needed here.

@Someprogrammerdude But since C++17, there is no temporary created in the = std::unique_ptr<Impl>(nullptr) case, or is it? I am pretty sure that the move constructor is not called/involved here.

Possibly relevant question: Why destructor needs to be accessible even when it is not called?
